# How to convert text to number in Excel or Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm not able to convert text to number.
I tried in Power Query "trim" and "delete space", but I'm still not able to convert it into number format.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to specify the correct culture (`from locale` if you are using the UI). If that doesn't work, a representative **text** sample (not a picture) and tell us your method of getting it into PQ; along with your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: To expand: That function has an optional parameter for your culture/locale. Setting this is very important, because it totally changes how dates and numbers are coerced. -- If unset, query will change depending on the machine it runs on. The screenshot is missing `"es-es"` (or your culture)  `= TransformColumnTypes( Source, {{"Col1", Int64.Type},{"Date", Date.Type}, "es-es")` -- Or if you're using a from function add the culture as well. 

If `= Number.FromText("7.234,0", "de-de" )` -- If not, you can get some silent errors that are way off. ( going de -> en and back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the space.
It didn't work if I just type a space and replace it with nothing.
I had to copy the space.
I don't know why the spaces are different from each other. But this works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere",{{"ColumnNameGoesHere", each Number.From(Text.Select(_,{"0".."9"})), type number}})
```

Comment: `Text.Clean` should strip the whitespace for you. Also add the `culture` parameter to [Number.FromText\()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-fromtext) to ensure they coerce the same regardless of the machine

Comment: I don't believe Text.Clean does spaces mid text and I'm not sure what the character in the middle is so I went with Text.Select

Comment: Indeed text.clean doesn't work. I had to copy the space in between then replace it with nothing. If I just type " ", it doesn't work

Comment: I tried this : = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Dernières lignes supprimées", {{"Nombre total d'impressions - Copier", each Number.From(Text.Select( " ",{"0".."9"})), type number}})    Expression.Eror : 2 arguments ont été passés à une fonction qui en attendait entre 3 et 4.
Détails :
    Pattern=
    Arguments=[List]

Comment: Why are you using Table.DuplicateColumn when my answer was to use Table.TransformColumns? They are not the same thing

Comment: `Text.Clean` does remove control chars in the middle, only excluding space. The docs don't mention it. `= [ sample = "a#(cr,lf)bc ", cleaned = Text.Clean( sample ), len1 = Text.Length(sample), len2 = Text.Length(cleaned), removed = len1 <> len2 ]`

Comment: Great. Learn something new every day